# SQL Server decimal division not rounding the result

Tags: sql-server, decimal

I tried the below multiplication and division and expected same result with rounding. Both operations has result type as Decimal(38,6)
I want to know why result is not rounded in case of division?

result should be rounded for both multiplication and division as per below link
[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
select cast(1.225114854 as decimal(38, 9)) * cast(1.000000000 as decimal(28, 9)) as multiply
```

Result : 1.225115

```
select cast(1.225114854 as decimal(38, 9)) / cast(1.000000000 as decimal(28, 9)) as division
```

Result: 1.225114

```
select 1.225114854 / 1.000000000
```

Result: 1.22511485400000000000

Comment: Could simply wrap entire thing in `Round()` function

Answer (score 2):

The way SQL server behaves in case of multiplication and division of decimal numbers is different, hence the difference in number of digits:

Assuming, `e1=decimal(p1,s1) and e2=decimal(p2,s2)`

```
Operation   Result precision                        Result scale *
e1 + e2     max(s1, s2) + max(p1-s1, p2-s2) + 1     max(s1, s2)
e1 - e2     max(s1, s2) + max(p1-s1, p2-s2) + 1     max(s1, s2)
e1 * e2     p1 + p2 + 1                             s1 + s2
e1 / e2     p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)      max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)
```

The result precision and scale have an absolute maximum of 38. When a result precision is greater than 38, the corresponding scale is reduced to prevent the integral part of a result from being truncated.

Because of this, when you are multiplying 38 precision decimals, the result becomes truncated. You can use the following calculation to get better results:

```
select cast(1.225114854 as decimal(15,9))*cast(1.000000000  as decimal(15,9)) as multiply
select cast(1.225114854 as decimal(15,9))/cast(1.000000000  as decimal(15,9)) as division
```

The following link should be able to clarify most of your doubts:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/769823/Losing-Precision-After-Multiplication-in-SQL-Serve

Comment: I want to understand why division does not do rounding while reducing scale to 6. In both multiplication and division case result scale is more than 6. So both operations should do rounding on result.

I referred this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Looks like it gets truncated in case of division and gets round off in case of multiplication...SQL Server has it's issues with mathematical calculations...

Comment: If you want accurate rounded off results, use the round function

Comment: sure,
 I need to mimic this behavior in spark sql. so i was trying to get clarification. I will try more example to conclude the behavior.

Comment: Cool, if you find something else, make sure you add it here :)

Comment: based on my observation, for division rounding mode is DOWN and for multiplication rounding mode is UP.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with converting SQL Server to Spark.

Both SQL Server and Spark use the same rules for determining precision and scale for results of arithmetic operations, listed in @CR7SMS's answer.

I believe the problem is the [SQL Server documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) you shared is incorrect, because it uses the word "round" specifically: "Result might be rounded to 6 decimal places".  But division truncates rather than rounds.

I resolved this in Spark by using a UDF for division that replicates the behavior in SQL Server:

```
val divide = udf((x: BigDecimal, y: BigDecimal) => x.divide(y, 6, RoundingMode.FLOOR))
```